# Trouble with adding additional column with JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

Have two tables:

[image]

Task:

Make a table with fields:

- name of acquiring_company;
- name of acquired_company;
- `price_amount`;
- `funding_total`;

Ignore those transactions in which the purchase amount (price_amount) and amount of investment (funding_total) is zero

```
SELECT
a.acquiring_company_id,
a.acquired_company_id,
a.price_amount,
c.funding_total
FROM acquisition a
LEFT JOIN company c
    ON a.acquired_company_id = c.id
WHERE price_amount <> 0 AND funding_total <> 0
```

Maybe a dumb question, but how can I add names to acquiring_company and acquired_company (`company.name`)? I don't understand it because there  are two `id` fields. I can't use JOIN on both of them.

Comment: Move company column conditions from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result. (As it is now, you get regular INNER JOIN result.) However, I _think_ you want INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the same table twice with different alias names

```
SELECT a.acquired_company_id, c1.name as acquired_company_name,
       a.acquiring_company_id, c2.name as acquiring_company_name,           
       a.price_amount,
       c1.funding_total
FROM acquisition a
LEFT JOIN company c1 ON a.acquired_company_id = c1.id
LEFT JOIN company c2 ON a.acquiring_company_id = c2.id
WHERE a.price_amount <> 0 
  AND c1.funding_total <> 0
```

Answer (score 2):

> I can't use JOIN on both of them.

Yes, you can. And should.

```sql
SELECT
    a.acquiring_company_id,
    a.acquired_company_id,
    a.price_amount,
    c1.funding_total,
    c1.name as acquired_company_name,
    c2.name as acquiring_company_name
FROM acquisition a
LEFT JOIN company c1
    ON a.acquired_company_id = c1.id
LEFT JOIN company c2
    ON a.acquiring_company_id = c2.id
WHERE price_amount <> 0 AND c1.funding_total <> 0
```

Test the query in [Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/-wVsun7b)